# Mongo locale variant meaning

Tags: mongodb, collation

Some mongoDB locales have variants: for instance Catalan has variant *search* and Spanish has variants *search* and *traditional*. What do those variants mean and what effect do they have on string comparisons? MongoDB documentation specifies which variants are available for each supported language (see [this page from their maunal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation-locales-defaults/)) but it does not specify what do they mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collation data comes from [CLDR - Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads).

Downloading the [common archive](http://unicode.org/Public/cldr/38/cldr-common-38.0.zip) and looking for the `ca` locale (`common/collation/ca.xml`), it has the following notes. Standard variant:

```
    <!-- standard collation &L<<ŀ=l·<<<Ŀ=L· is equivalent to root collation order
        (except root uses prefix rules for the middle dot, rather than contractions)
        references="Enciclopèdia Catalana: Diccionari de la llengua catalana ISBN 84-85194-46-2" -->
```

Search variant:

```
            # Below are the rules specific to ca.
            # Per Apple language group, these are modified from standard rules below
            # to make L primary-different from L-dot for search.
```